# How to build user-based funnel split by month and device category in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to build user-based funnel split by device category using data from google analytics. Funnel steps are both page and event-based.

As a final result, I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Tried one approach suggested in one of StackOverflow threads, but v1 attempt let the query run forever (>10 mins with no result just for 1 day of data).

Below you can see the code I use.

Step 1 - build the raw data that contains raw log of events I'll use for sequencing and analysis:

```
#standardSQL
-- Step 1: Identify Prospect Segment + get the baseline for funnel development

WITH arrAgg AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullvisitorid,
    device.deviceCategory,
    -- concatenate arrays over multiple sessions
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(hits ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC) userHits
  FROM
    `XXX.ga_sessions_20200824` g
    WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.campaign, '^mem_')
    AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium, 'member')
    AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.source, 'member')
    AND NOT (select count(1)>0 from unnest(hits) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, '/health-insurance/(.*)/declaration'))
    AND NOT (select count(1)>0 from unnest(hits) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, '/members/'))

  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
, journey AS (
  SELECT 
    date,
    fullvisitorId,
    deviceCategory,
    -- get a proper running index with combination of unnest and offset of aggregated hits array
    ARRAY( (SELECT AS STRUCT index+1 as hitNumber, page, eventInfo FROM UNNEST(userHits) WITH OFFSET AS index)) as hits,
    
  FROM arrAgg
  )
  
  select * from journey
```

On step 2, I run the condition-driven sequence that aggregates user volume if fullvisitorid is present across both steps.

```
First 2 steps + segmentation look like below:

    #standardSQL
    -- Step 1: Identify Prospect Segment + get the baseline for funnel development
    
    WITH arrAgg AS (
      SELECT
        date,
        fullvisitorid,
        device.deviceCategory,
        -- concatenate arrays over multiple sessions
        ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(hits ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC) userHits
      FROM
        `XXX.ga_sessions_20200824` g
        WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.campaign, '^mem_')
        AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium, 'member')
        AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.source, 'member')
        AND NOT (select count(1)>0 from unnest(hits) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, '/health-insurance/(.*)/declaration'))
        AND NOT (select count(1)>0 from unnest(hits) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, '/members/'))
    
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
    , journey AS (
      SELECT 
        date,
        fullvisitorId,
        deviceCategory,
        -- get a proper running index with combination of unnest and offset of aggregated hits array
        ARRAY( (SELECT AS STRUCT index+1 as hitNumber, page, eventInfo FROM UNNEST(userHits) WITH OFFSET AS index)) as hits,
        
      FROM arrAgg
      )
      
-- Step 2: setting up scale-based funnel - visited scale page
SELECT deviceCategory,
SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, 'singles/$|couples/$|family/$|single-parents/$')), 1, 0) FROM j.hits) ) prod_comp_page,

-- cross join hits array with itself: combination of all pages with all pages: any of those combinations our two pages? came home before login?: if yes for any given amount add up 1
  SUM( (SELECT IF( LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(a.page.pagePath, 'singles/$|couples/$|family/$|single-parents/$')
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(b.page.pagePath, 'health-insurance/cover/.*')

  AND a.hitNumber < b.hitNumber) ,1, 0 ) FROM j.hits a CROSS JOIN j.hits b) ) prod_page_prosp
  
  from journey j
group by deviceCategory
```

As a result, I am getting the below:

[image]

However, when I run query on 1 day worth of data using all 6 steps of the funnel (as on the top picture), BQ runs forever without giving any result. Obviously, it's impossible to extend the timeframe as well.

Comment: Can you explain how is your input data? (give some example if possible)

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "user funnel".  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would make it more likely that the question would be answered.

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff , I've clarified the query to make clearer what's happening there and what I'm trying to achieve. Please let me know if this makes more sense now.

Comment: @R.Esteves I've changed my query. Please have a look and let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: @KirillKonovalov can you explain why do you need this cross join?

Comment: @R.Esteves That allows to check if fullvisitorid is present in both steps 1 and 2 prior to aggregation.  Without it I won't be able to compare if the previous step followed by next step using hit No?